# Is it possible to get event mailing (confirmation etc.) into a Persons activities?

Tags: civievent, activities

It seems like activities like CiviCRM sending event registration confirmations etc. does not show up in the list of activities on the "Activity" tab.

Is it possible to make them do that or would that be a "feature request"?